Error "WebAssetManager is locked, you came late" in Joomla
I'm using Joomla 4.4, and this code to load a module to display it in a plugin.
echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadmoduleid 16}');

error
But the website say error WebAssetManager is locked, you came late
If I use {loadmoduleid 16} in a Joomla article it still working fine. I don't sure what's wrong?
Please help.
Thanks
WebAssetManager is locked, you came late
